# Gathering data from rate limited API in Power BI

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I've recently discovered that Power BI is available through my enterprise O365 account and I've been asked to start exploring dashboarding for a few of our tools. One of these tools uses a RESTful API to make data available and I have already successfully made the connection between it and Power BI.

However, this API limits the maximum number of results returned in a single call, so I would have to make multiple calls with a start value to receive the next set, then increment the start value by the final value returned in the previous set, and so on. Basically something like...

```
startAt = 0
do{
  makeAPICall(startAt, results)
  startAt += results.last()
}(while results.last() != END)
```

I can't figure out how I can get Power BI to connect to the 'complete' data source. Sure I can manually create N separate calls and manually set the starting value, but it won't scale to meet future needs unless I keep adding new calls when I max out the existing set or stick in a ton of currently null calls to allow for growth.

Is this paginated API functionality able to be utilized in Power BI? If so, how?

Comment: Can you add the exact API you're using?

Comment: @FoxanNg - I'm seeking a solution for the general case as this may crop up with other tools as we work on implementation, but the specific API I'm trying to manage at the moment is for Workfront.

Comment: If you can provide your already working M query in Power BI for this specific API (Workfront), I'm sure it'll be much easier for us to provide a working solution, while along with proper explanation you can easily generalize it to other cases, rather than us throwing a random "generalized" solution in pseudo code, which may or may not fit your case.